# Bootstrap 3 - Fixed height for all pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

At the moment when I load up a different webpage the div gets smaller and the footer goes up or down dependent of what content it inside the div.

Can someone help me as to why this happening.

My Code (slightly different as using Flask):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>WBP Assignment</title>
  <meta name="keywords" content="UEA, University, Coursework, York, Cottage, WBP, Web, Based, Programming">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"><!--mobile first :p -->
  <meta name="description" content="UEA Undergraduate coursework assignment">
  <meta name="author" content="Matthew Wilson, Pedro Bernardina">

  <!--Bootstrap CSS-->
  <link href="static/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="static/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!--Bootstrap Core JS-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="static/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/scripts.js"></script>
</head>

<body background="templates/background.jpg">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-12 column">
            <!-- A carousel inside the jumbotron, sliding data every 3000ms. -->
            <div class="carousel slide" id="carousel-274384" data-interval="3000" data-ride="carousel"><!--carousel begin-->
                <div class="carousel-inner">

                    <div class="item active"><!--begin item-->
                            <img alt="" src="static/img/1.JPG">
                    </div><!--end item-->

                    <div class="item"><!--begin item-->
                        <img alt="" src="static/img/2.JPG">
                    </div><!--end item-->

                    <div class="item">
                        <img alt="" src="static/img/3.JPG">
                    </div><!--end item-->

                    <div class="item">
                        <img alt="" src="static/img/4.JPG">
                    </div><!--end item-->

                    <div class="item">
                        <img alt="" src="static/img/5.JPG">
                    </div><!--end item-->
                </div><!--end carousel inner--> 

            </div><!--end carouseul-->

            <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">York Cottage</a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/features">Features</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/gallery">Gallery</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/comments">Comments</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>

            </nav>
            <div class="row clearfix">
            {% block content %}
            <div class="content">

                <div class="col-md-12 column" >

                    {% if pageType == "index" %}
                    <h3> {{ title }} </h3>

                    {% for p in paragraph %}
                    <p> {{ p }}</p>
                    {%  endfor %}



                    <a href="http://www.southern-comfort.co.uk/" class="img-responsive" target="_blank"><img alt="" width="550" src="static/img/comfort.jpeg"></a>

                    {% endif %}

                    {% if pageType == "features" %} <!-- if vistor clicks features then index body disappears and features appears -->

                    <h3> {{ title }} </h3>

                    <ul>
                      <li>Living Room: Spacious open plan sitting room. Two sofas, 42" flat screen TV. DVD, Video, CD Player. </li>
                      <li>Kitchen/ Diner: Well equipped fitted kitchen with washing machine, dishwasher and microwave. Large dinning table with six chairs. </li>
                      <li>Bedroom 1: Double bed with an en-suite room. Fitted wardrobes.</li>
                      <li> Bedroom 2: Double bed with fiited wardrobes </li>
                      <li> Bedroom 3: Two twin beds with a fitted wardrobe</li>
                      <li> Bedroom 4: Single bed with two large fitted wardrobes</li>
                      <li> Upstairs Bathroom: Upstairs bathroom with bath</li>
                      <li> Downstairs Bathroom: Bathroom with power shower</li>
                      <li> Patio picnic bench overlooking heated swimming pool. Large front garden with driveway for three cars. </li>
                    </ul>
                    {% endif %}


                </div>
            {% endblock %}
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1 column">
            </div><!--right margin-->


            <div class="row clearfix">

                <div class="col-md-1 column">
                </div><!--left margin-->

                <div class="col-md-12 column" id="footer"><!--footer-->
                    <p>Matthew Wilson
                        <br/>Pedro Bernardina
                        <br/>Norwich Research Park, NR4 7TJ
                        <br/>University of East Anglia
                        <br/>All Rights Reserved
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-1 column">
                </div><!--right margin-->

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-inner{
  width:100%;
  max-height: 28em !important;
}

.navbar-default {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;


    }


div#jumbotron {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

div#map_canvas {
  height:45em;
  background-color: black;
}

div#main_cmt {
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: white;
  height: 50em;
  margin-top: 2em;

}

ul#navbar {
  background-color:white;
}

div#content {
  background-color: white;
  height: 50em;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

div#extra {
  background-color: white;
  height: 50em;
  margin-top: 2em;
  text-align: justify;
}

div#footer {
  background-color: #484848;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-top: 2cm;
}



body {
  background: url("..\FlaskApp\FlaskApp\templates\background.jpg");
}
/* resizes images in the website when screen is smaller */

   img {
          display: block;
          height: auto;
          max-width: 100%;
   }


/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the div container doesn't have a fixed height.  If you want to make it a fixed height just add this to your files

**HTML:**

Change this

```
<div class="container">
```

to

```
<div class="container fixed-height">
```

**CSS:**

Add this to css file

```
div.fixed-height {
height: 900px !important;
}
```

You can change the height to whatever you want.  Also I don't advise this if you are just trying to keep the footer to the bottom of the page.  There are other ways to do that if you look around the internet.

Comment: Oh no! Its just for the content div I want them to all be a fixed height. This didn't work for me though sadly :(

Comment: ah ok then just add the class fixed-height to the content div and remove from container div

Comment: try it now with the update I added !important.  This overrides bootstrap's css.

Comment: :D please select answer to question so it will close question